# Sequence in Amazon SimpleDB

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

Created a new Domain in amazon simple DB . So I would to like provide unique number for ITEM NAME through a sequence as in oracle . Is it possible to create a sequence in Amazon Simple DB ? if so how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleDB API` does not support `sequence`. You can use third party tool which `generate auto sequence of unique numbers` for `itemName` called [SDBExplorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/). From documentation -

[Import data form My-Sql to Amazon SimpleDB using auto generate Item Name](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--how-to-upload-my-sql-data-with-auto-generated-item-name.html)

[Import data form CSV to Amazon SimpleDB using auto generate Item Name](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--how-to-upload-csv-file-data-with-auto-generated-item-name.html)

[Upload data using Direct Cell Editor with an Auto Generated Item Name](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--how-to-upload-bulk-data-using-direct-cell-editor-with-auto-generated-item-name.html)